# How to define values of a data.frame that are outside a range as NA?

Tags: r, optimization

I am currently trying to create a routine that helps me to clean my datasets. For some numeric / integer variables there is a range (min & max) where values are allowed. Values that are not contained within that ranged should be declared as NA.

My current code:

```
df$variable[df$variable < min.range && df$variable > max.range] <- NA
```

Or as an alternative:

```
df$variable[!df$variable %in% c(min.range:max.range)] <- NA
```

I am wondering which one would be more efficient since the datasets can be quite big and I want to keep the processing time as short as possible. Maybe there is even a better way to solve the problem.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: @CathG fixed that, thank you! ;)

Comment: No need for `c(…)` in your code.

Answer (score 2):

Your first way of doing it is wrong for 2 reasons:

- Firstly, a value cannot be `< min.range` and `> max.range`, you need an `or` there.
- Secondly, you don't need a double `&` or `|` that will only check the first value.

You thus need to replace your first line of code by:

```
df$variable[df$variable < min.range | df$variable > max.range] <- NA
```

For the second way, it can only work with integers.

Regarding the efficiency, you can test both your ways with a relatively large data.frame:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(matrix(floor(rnorm(50000*1000, 100, 10)), nrow=50000))
colnames(df)[1] <- "variable"
min.range <- 85
max.range <- 115
meth1 <- function(){df$variable[df$variable < min.range | df$variable > max.range] <- NA; df}
meth2 <- function(){df$variable[!df$variable %in% c(min.range:max.range)] <- NA; df}

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(meth1(), meth2(), unit="relative")
#   expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
# meth1() 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000   100  a 
# meth2() 1.588484 1.603514 1.581301 1.597115 1.564948 1.481916   100   b
```

To sum up:
- modify your first method if you want to make it work
- don't use the second one if you are not working with integers
- even if you're working with integers, the first way is more efficient

Answer (score 1):

You can get the execution time of your alternatives like this:

```
#processing time of option 1
system.time({ 
 df$variable[df$variable < min.range && df$variable > max.range] <- NA
}) 

#processing time of option 2
system.time({ 
 df$variable[!df$variable %in% c(min.range:max.range)] <- NA
})
```

(don't forget to reinitialize your `df`between the 2 tests)